# Iterate through table to do geometric calculation

Tags: postgis, postgresql, iteration

I've got two tables:

- tableA holds the objects with it's geometry
- tableB holds holds pairs
  of two objects (ids, each in a separate column) from table1

Now I want to calculate the concaveHull for the pairs in each row coming from tableB.
The SQL (for one pair only) is quit simple:

```
SELECT ST_ConcaveHull (ST_Collect(tA.geom),1)
FROM tableA AS tA
WHERE id IN (250,214)
```

The `"WHERE id IN (250,214)"` is an example object pair stored in tableB.

How can I do this calculation for each pair from tableB iterative?
With joins or loops? I cannot get it work.

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right you should be using two `JOIN`s on your `<tableB>`:

```
SELECT ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(a.geom, b.geom), <value_lower_than_1.0>[, TRUE | FALSE]) AS geom
FROM   <tableA> AS ref
JOIN   <tableB> AS a
  ON   ref.<id1> = a.<id>
JOIN   <tableB> AS b
  ON   ref.<id2> = b.<id>
;
```

You may want an index `ON <tableB> (<id>)`, if not the `PRIMARY KEY` already.

---

Note that the `target_percent` parameter should be smaller than `1.0` to actually create a concave hull; using `1.0` will be equal to `ST_ConvexHull`! That value has **a rather logarithmic impact on computation time**, and likely a strong impact on the resulting shape of the hull; decrease slowly by steps in the range of `0.01` to test for the desired result!
The second parameter will allow holes (inner rings) in the hull; default is `FALSE`.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really calculated the expected. My pairs table (tableB) contains 489 lines. The result of your query returns 1537 rows with point, line and polygon geom (whereas I was especting polygons only). And that's because it does not take the pairs (like pairID1 and pairID2) but the geom are formed from pairID1 and pairID1. Could I provide any further information on the orig tables?